# How to handle many "Then" step definitions?

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin, citrus-framework

Consider a scenario with multiple "Then" step definitions meant to be used as assertions against a response payload:

```
  ...
  When a response is received
  Then the response should have an element "foo" with the content "bar"
  And the response should contain 1 "foobar" element
  And the response should have an element "rab" with the content "oof"
  ...
```

What is the intended way for Citrus to handle an unknown amount of validations? Can you define several validators before calling `receive()`? Can this be handled with a `validationCallback()` and minimal Gherkin rewrite?

The current implementation uses `validationCallback()` to store the payload as an instance variable, then validate against the variable. However, it would be much better to leverage the power of Citrus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use named messages in a `Given` section or even in a scenario background:

```
Given message fooResponse
    And <fooResponse> payload is "Hi my name is Foo!"
    And <fooResponse> header operation is "sayHello"
    ...
```

You can use the named message in a scenario like this:

```
Scenario: Send and receive
  When <client> sends message <fooRequest>
  Then <client> should receive message <fooResponse>
```

The validation of all elements is done automatically as the Citrus validator compares received and expected message contents.

Also you could extract the message creation to a Java POJO message creator:

```
Background:
  Given message creator com.consol.citrus.FooMessageCreator

public class FooMessageCreator {
    @MessageCreator("fooResponse")
    public Message createEchoResponse() {
        return new DefaultMessage("Hi my name is Foo!")
                    .setHeader("operation", "sayHello");
    }
}
```

In case you need to deal with large XML/Json payloads you can also load that payloads from external file template resource. Instead of setting each element in a separate explicit `Then` statement you should go for template based compare validation that can also use `@ignore@` sections for ignoring parts of the message that are not relevant for validation.

Comment: Using XML templates is what we've ended up doing instead of using `n` amount of `Then`/`And`s.